# Use OpenLayers Save Strategy without adding layer to map

Tags: openlayers

Is there anyway to use a save strategy on a layer (for use in a data table) without having to first add the layer to the map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add 'isBaseLayer: true' to the layer on creation it won't draw it when you then come to add it later.